# Java: Count number of letters in text file

Tags: java, count, character

How do I count the total number of each letter? I think I can use  `StringUtils.countMatches` but I am not sure how to use it.

Also, do i need to put spaces between characters so that my program will count them? If so, this is what I have and it will not work:

Code to add spaces:

```
char ch;
ch = next().CharAt(0);

switch (ch) {

   case 'A': System.out.print ("A ");
             break;
   case 'B': System.out.print ("B ");
             break;
   case 'C': System.out.print ( "C ");
             break;
  }
```

THANK YOU ALL SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 0):

The best general approach (I'll leave you to work out the exact code) is to maintain an array that stores a count for each character. A `char` in Java is a 16-bit unsigned integer, which means that you can declare

```
int[] counts = new int[65536];
```

and then when you want to register an occurrence of character `c`, you can

```
counts[(int) c]++;
```

In order to get the individual characters, you could read the file line by line, and then go through the `String` representing each line, and process it:

```
for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++) {
    counts[(int) line.getCharAt(i)]++;
}
```

And then at the end you can read off your array to determine how many times each character turned up.

Technically you don't need to bother with the `(int)` type conversions, and you can just write

```
count[line.getCharAt(i)]++;
```

but it might be clearer what's going on if you explicitly convert.

Comment: You could also use a `Map<Character, Integer>` to count, especially if you assume a text in a ASCII-based language where you'll need only a fraction of the huge array.